# Windows Server 2003 and IIS6.0: Switching website to a DR server

Tags: networking, windows-server-2003, iis-6, dns-hosting

I am a .NET developer who now has to handle both development and deployment of an ASP.NET/ASMX/WebAPI application at my new job, though I have no prior experience with IIS or Windows Server Networking beyond setting up very simple intranet company fileservers and workstations.

We have a Production and Test server for this website. Both servers have multiple IP addresses assigned to their network interface cards: one each for the machine itself and several others used for sites hosted on the machines.

I want to set up a copy of the Production environment on the Test server that can be switched over in case of the Production server failing. It doesn't have to be automatic, I can do it manually.

How do I redirect http requests to the Production server over to the Test server? Should I transfer the IP addresses of the production server to Test? Or do I have to update a DNS entry for our website somewhere (the companies ISP?) to point at the Test server instead. If either works, what do people usually do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I redirect http requests to the Production server over to the Test server?

You change DNS. Given taht the old server may be down as in burning and in flames - there is nothing you can do on that machine, literally.

> Should I transfer the IP addresses of the production server to Test?

That is fastest but assumes that is possible. IP routing upstream can not be manipulated - so it requires same rack (bad in case of desaster) or same data center (cooperation from hoster).

> what do people usually do?

Depends how tiny they are. Small - DNS. Middle: Load balancer that takes out the defective server. Large: Multiple data centers, unicast routing, rerouting via routing policy updates for their AS.

Comment: Seems like DNS change is the best option for us, especially given that we do not physically control the servers, someone else hosts them. Thanks.